# Replace não esta funcionando C#

Tags: c#, string, txt, replace

Estou substituindo um código por outro em cada linha que o código é encontrado.
Mas o replace simplesmente não funciona, passa por ele e a linha continua do mesmo jeito. Como podem ver na imagem abaixo, se utilizo dentro do immediate, aparece que deu certo, mas ao verificar o conteúdo da string verifico que continuou da mesma forma.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
        string texto = string.Empty;
        int contadorCodigos = 0;
        int contadorLinhas = 0;
        string linha = string.Empty;
        string[] linhas = new string[_linhas.Count()];

        foreach (string line in _linhas)
        {
            linha = line;

            foreach (var item in _codigos)
            {
                if (line.Contains(item.Key))
                {
                    linha.Replace(item.Key, item.Value);
                    //line.Replace(item.Key, item.Value);
                    texto += $" {item.Key} - {item.Value};";
                    contadorCodigos++;
                    break;
                }
            }

            linhas[contadorLinhas] = linha;
            contadorLinhas++;
        }

        txtResultado.Text = texto;
        txtQtdCodigosTrocados.Text = contadorCodigos.ToString();
```

Alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O método `Replace()` retorna um um valor, e esse valor é que você não está acumulando em lugar algum.

Mude sua linha para:

```
linha = linha.Replace(item.Key, item.Value);
```

Assim vc irá acumular o resultado do `Replace()` de volta na variável `linha` como esperado.

Comment: Muito obrigado Thiago, erro idiota da minha parte rsrs

Comment: Erro honesto. Acontece com todos.