# Como Substituir caracteres por outro com C#

Tags: c#, programação-funcional

Por exemplo:
4587 / 1235 / 7554
E depois de substituido
4587;1235;7554

Remove os espaços e no lugar da barra, coloca ponto e virgula, como faz isso no C#?

Comment: Já olhou para o método `Replace` de `string` ? Tem por ai vários exemplos, tal como [este](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/309126/c-remover-aspas-replace-remover-asp-duplas) ou [este](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/176403/replace-n%C3%A3o-esta-funcionando-c)

Answer (score 1):

```
 string string1 = "44 / 44 / 55";
 string string2  = string1.Replace(" / ",";");
```

Comment: Então cara, é que as vezes vai ter número assim 4527 4524 7852 onde no lugar do espaço, terá ponto e virgula, e desse jeito q vc fez, terá 3 ponto e virgula

Comment: Terá apenas dois.

Comment: @Renan quando se faz um pergunta deve colocar todo o conjunto de informações e variações que possam ocorrer, o que foi respondido é o que foi perguntado, após isso você coloca outra regra no comentário, deveria então verificar a sua pergunta porque falta informações  ... se concorda? (as próximas perguntas coloque todas as regras ... )